# File not found for PHP download

Tags: php

I have a script that gets a url for an mp3 track based on the ID sent via a GET variable in the url. The script then forces a download of this url. The problem i'm having is that the track is not found.

```
$url = $row['url'];
$file_name = $row['track_name'] .' - '. $row['artist_name'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url); //get path info
$base_url  = $path_parts['basename']; //only include mp3 track just incase path added in there
$file_path  = '../uploads/' . $base_url; 
if (file_exists($file_path)) {
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
     header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_path));
 ob_clean();
     flush();
 readfile($file_path);
 exit;
}

else {
    echo 'File not found.';
    echo '<br/>';
echo $file_path;
}
```

What is show is something like this;

```
File not found.
../uploads/demo_4.wav
```

I have tried putting the full url as `$file_path`, so `http://localhost/upload/ ...` but the same thing happens.

If i enter the URL directly the file is there so i'm not exactly sure what is going on.

Comment: Remember that what readfile/filexists see is the FILESYSTEM, which may not correspond at all to URL space. just because you have `http://example.com/download/demo_4.wav` doesn't mean there'll actually be a `download` directory in your site's document root.

Comment: @MarcB There is an uploads directory though which I have linked to. `$file_path  = '../uploads/' . $base_url; `

Comment: Where is this script located relative to the file ? Is the uploads directory one level up from where this script is located at ?

Comment: tried `$file_path = './uploads/'`?

Comment: @azizpunjani the script is on the document root and the file is in a subfolder. That does not matter though as even if I use `http://localhost/uploads/...` as the url to download it still is not found

Comment: which means that uploads is in a parallel location to where this script is running. e.g. `/www/site/foo/script.php` and `/www/site/uploads/demo_4.wav`

Comment: Then do `$file_path = 'uploads/'.$base_url;`

Comment: did you try `$file_path  = './uploads/' . $base_url;` ?

Comment: nbs `http://localhost/uploads/` will not work because it's a url and doesn't correspond to the filesystem path that the `file_exists` function will check.

Comment: How stupid of me! Yes, `./uploads/` works

Comment: Leading `./` is unnecessary `uploads/` will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the script outside of the root folder, you want to use the relative path, try:

```
$file_path  = './uploads/' . $base_url;
```

If you are running the script in the root folder and simply want to access a subfolder, try:

```
$file_path  = 'uploads/' . $base_url;
```

Comment: leading `./` is unnecessary.

Comment: @azizpunjani Updated to hopefully remove confusion. I originally read it as he was not in the root folder, hence my original `./`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: JClaspill `./` would not take you to the root. The `.` means the current directory, `./` would take you to the current directory as well. `/` would take you to the root directory.... You can try it out in the shell do a `cd ./` and it will not take you anywhere, do a `cd /` from a sub-directory and it will take you to the root.

Answer (score 2):

If the image's path is **root_folder/uploads/filename**, try the following

```
 
  $file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/uploads/" . filename;
```

The point of the answer is this: rather than using relative paths, use the absolute path to the file, where everything up till the root folder is referenced by **$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]**. 
 
Hope the explanation is clear and the answer helps.

Comment: It always works for me. And unless the path is somewhat manipulated, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.